# How can I invoke the breakpoint correctly in VSCode while attach the process?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I created a .net core project with Visual Studio on a local computer.

Now I want to debug it on the server computer(Windows Server 2012R2).

I have to do it like this for the project has used a third-party API which only can work one a formal URL but not localhost.

Therefore, I copy the project to the server computer and use the VSCode to attach the process.

However, when the breakpoint invokes, VSCode reports this error:
[image]

Well, on the local computer the project is store in `g:\Github\SI-Customservice\SI-Customservice\`, but why it still tries to access the path while on a different computer?

I think there must be a variable saving the path in the project but I can not find it.

And also, I don't want to modify the path I store on the local computer.

How can I solve it? Thank you.

PS：
Here is launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the problem solved.

It is not the problem of the Visual Studio Code but the project which is published.

I should not publish the project on the local computer.

After I publish the project by the VSCode on the server computer. All works.